# why does my browser reloads when using ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

i created an ajax function that when clicked by a user it adds a messages to his favorites tab. i want it to work similar to a twitter like button so when a user clicks the favorite button it does not reload the page. i created everything correctly and even the ajax function calls the php file and inserts everything into the database, its just that it still reloads the page after the clicking.

my ajax code:

```
 <script>
        function GetXmlHttpObject() { 
      var xmlHttp=null; 
      try 
        { 
        // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari 
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        }
    catch (e) 
        { 
        // Internet Explorer 
        try 
            { xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); } 
        catch (e) 
            { xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
        } 
    r  eturn xmlHttp; 
   }
      function ajaxfav(){
       var xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
       var url="favorite.php?message="+document.msgidform.fav_message.value;
      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
        alert("Message is favorited");

        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);

}
  </script>
```

my php code:

```
   $user_id = $_SESSION['active_user_id'];
    extract($_POST);
    extract($_GET);
    if(isset($_GET['message']))
    {
        $id=$_GET['message'];

        $q=$db->prepare("SELECT msgid,date,text

        FROM messages 
        WHERE to_id=? and msgid=?");
        $q->bindValue(1,$user_id);
        $q->bindValue(2,$id);
        $q->execute();
        $row2=$q->fetch();
        $d=$row2['date'];


        $fav_questionq=$db->prepare("SELECT *
        FROM messages
        LEFT JOIN users
        ON messages.to_id=users.id
        WHERE users.id=? AND messages.msgid=?

        ");
        $fav_questionq->bindValue(1,$user_id);
        $fav_questionq->bindValue(2,$id);
        $fav_questionq->execute();
        $frow=$fav_questionq->fetch();

        $fquestion= $frow['text'];


        $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM fav_messages
                            WHERE username=? AND message=?");
        $result-bindValue(1,$user_id);  
        $result-bindValue(2,$id);               
        $result->execute();


    if($result->rowCount()== 1 )
    {
        $deletequery=$db->prepare("DELETE FROM fav_messages WHERE message=?");
        $deletequery->bindValue(1,$id);
        $deletequery->execute();
    echo("<script>location.href = 'index.php?a=recieved';</script>");
    }
    else
    {
    $insertquery = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO fav_messages (username,message,fav_question,fav_date) values(?,?,?,?)");
    $insertquery->bindValue(1,$user_id);
    $insertquery->bindValue(2,$id);
    $insertquery->bindValue(3,$fquestion);
    $insertquery->bindValue(4,$d);
    $insertquery-execute();
    }
    echo("<script>location.href = 'index.php?a=recieved';</script>");
    }
```

my html code:

```
     <form name="msgidform" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="fav_message" id="" <?php echo "value= '$msg_id'"; ?>></p>
    </form>



           <a class="msg-icon" href="" onclick="ajaxfav();"><img
            src="images/linedfav.png" id='img'></img></a>
```

why does my browser still reloads even though i am using ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's is because you're using `<a>` tag, even in you don't provide a href attribute it will redirect you, in your case to homepage that's why you have the reload effect. A way to solve it would be to create a fake anchor tag by using `<span>`tag that would have the styles of `<a>` tag and attaching your ajax function to the `<span>` tag

Comment: can't he also use `preventDefault()` ?

Comment: Yes, it can be another solution

Comment: thats a good answer ts just how will it be clicked now? nothing is clickable other than the <a> tag

Comment: @Tarekas where would i put this preventDefault() function?

Comment: To attach a handler to onlick for span tag, you would need to use addEventListener function, preventDefault() you should put at the start of ajaxfav() function

Comment: just attach an id to the span , and in the jquery function make a click event handler corresponding to that ID 
e.g : `$("#myID").click ( functino() { //your fn here ..});`

Comment: @Tarekas you solution and terminat solved my reloading problem, i still have another issue, it seems that the ajax function only works for the first message and not the other messages, even though it is in a loop, please check my edited question

Comment: Can you check after you click on other messages if the request is also sent? Or is it just that the request is sent only for the first one.

Comment: the other requests are sent but with the same ID of the first message, it doesnt change the value of the id i mean that the ajax function doesnt take this value for every message it only takes it for the first message. ( <input type="hidden" name="fav_message" id="" <?php echo "value= '$msg_id'"; ?>) @Terminat

Comment: Seems like, there is a problem inside a loop that's creating these messages. You're probably passing always the first id  in the "value= '$msg_id'"